# How to use counter in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a program where a doctor sees only 5 patients and then the program ends.  Right now it's not ending and it keeps asking for the next patient.  Ignore the else in the doctor-driver-loop procedure.  I add one to count in that procedure but I guess it keeps going back to zero every time. How do I fix this?

```
(define count 0)

(define (new-patient counter)
  (if (= counter 5) (write-line 'doctor has seen 5 patients today so the day is now over)
    (visit-doctor (ask-patient-name))))

(define (doctor-driver-loop name earlier-responses)
  (newline)
 (write '**)
  (let ((user-response (read)))
   (cond ((equal? user-response '(goodbye))
         (write-line (list 'goodbye name))
         (write-line '(see you next week))
         (new-patient (+ 1 count)))
      (else (write-line (reply (responses-list earlier-responses user-response) user-response))
            (doctor-driver-loop name (responses-list earlier-responses user-response))))))

(define (visit-doctor name)
  (write-line (list 'hello name))
  (write-line '(what seems to be the trouble?))
  (doctor-driver-loop name initial-earlier-response))
```

Comment: You're never updating `count`, so every time you call `new-patient` you're passing `1` as the argument. `doctor-driver-loop` should take the count as an argument, and pass `(+ 1 count)` when it recurses.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
(new-patient (+ 1 count))
```

With these two lines:

```
(set! count (+ 1 count))
(new-patient count)
```

In your current code, `count` will *always* have a value of zero for each iteration of `doctor-driver-loop`, because its value was never updated - the `(+ 1 count)` part adds one to `count` *without* changing `count`, and the next time `doctor-driver-loop` get called, `count` will be zero again.

Be aware that this is a quick fix, but not the ideal solution. For starters, `count` should not be defined as a global variable, instead it should be a parameter to the driver loop that gets passed with an initial value of zero and incremented when calling `new-patient` with each patient that gets processed.

Comment: is there a way to keep a count without set! ?

Comment: @user2036340 yes, pass it as a parameter from the beginning, as I suggested above. Don't declare it as a global define, start from deleting `(define count 0)` and work from there.

Comment: I followed what you said - deleted the defined count, added count as a parameter to the doctor-driver-loop, and put 0 in the visit-doctor when it's calling doctor-driver-loop.  The problem is that visit-doctor is being called every time there is a new patient so 0 is always being passed to the doctor-driver-loop

Comment: No, don't pass 0 _every time_, just the first time yo call `doctor-driver-loop`. From that point on, pass around count, and update it when needed. It's hard to explain without looking at the complete code, but it's better this way - so you can figure it out by yourself.

Comment: There just doesn't seem to be a spot where i can set it only once...where would that be since I am calling doctor-driver-loop from visit-doctor which gets called from new-patient...

Comment: @user2036340 you should structure the program in such a way that the entry point (the procedure that starts the execution of the program) gets passed a value of 0, and from that point all successive calls on the procedure pass the same counter value and update it where appropriate